# How do I find the equivalence of the expression $e^{n\log(n)-(n+e)\log(n + e)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

> We want to find equivalence of the expression
>
> $$e^{n\log(n)-(n+e)\log(n + e)}$$

Note that:
$$\log(n+t)=\log\left[n\left(\frac{t}{n}+1\right)\right]=\log(n) + \frac{t}{n} +o\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)$$
Can we say that
$$n\log(n+t)=n\log(n) + t +o(t),$$
and then
$$u_n=e^{n\log(n)-(n+t)\log(n+t)}=e^{n\log(n)-n\log(n+t)-t\log(n+t)}\sim ?$$

Comment: Do you mean you want to find an asymptotic formula for the expression?

Answer (score 1):

The expression is the same as
$$e^{n\log(n)-(n+e)\log(n+e)}=\frac{n^n}{(n+e)^{n+e}}=\left[\left(1+\frac{-e}{n+e}\right)^{\frac{n+e}{-e}}\right]^{\frac{-e}{n+e}n}\frac{1}{(n+e)^e}\sim \frac{e^{-e}}{n^e}$$

Is that a simple enough expression?

Comment: could we say that sequence is diverge

Comment: @Educ That what is divergent? Are you studying the sum of all those terms? The limit of all those terms?

Comment: @Educ It is the same problem. The sequence tends to zero.

Comment: @Educ the sequence is convergent to zero. Yes, not divergent.

Comment: @Educ I saw it. It is the same problem. Hence the same answer, no?

Comment: @Educ Is it this one? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102819/u-n-exp-n-log-n-n-epsilon-logn-epsilon

Comment: sorry this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096925/lim-x-to-infty-fracxx-lfloor-x-rfloor-lfloor-x-rfloor